# rails: pass value of a text field to a helper function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm sure this is a basic question... I have a nested form where the nested object contains a text field. There is a link_to_function in the form that calls some javascript. I want to pass the javascript function the value of a hidden field in the form (image_type_id).

Can I reference this with some ruby or does this need javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `this` (or `this.parent`, depending on where your link is on the form) and use jQuery on the Javascript side to get the hidden value.

Comment: Santos: Why jQuery? It can be anything right? And I am guessing this most certainly would be Prototype, which is the default with Rails?

Comment: @nktokyo
"this" is, well, that :) Picture the following:
<form onsubmit="doSomething(this)">...</form>
When the javascript function doSomething(form) is called, inside it you can refer to the form as a DOM element.

@Swanand
Sure, jQuery is just what I'm used to, even with Rails. But you can use anything.

Comment: @nktokyo For instance, if inside the function you did (this is jQuery) $(form).hide(), this would hide the form. That's the use of "this".

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out from your hint